# Button updates its own OnClientClick and then executes that?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am a .NET newb so please bear with me.

I am working on an online store.  It requires the visitor to choose quantities they want and then click a button to choose a date for those items (tours).

I have two buttons - one reads their choices and updates the OnClientClick value of the other and when that one is clicked it executes a popup.  The project requires me to do the whole process with just one button.  Here's the rough outline of the particulars:

Setup button:

```
    //Calculates parameters to send to popup based on control contents.
    public void btnSetup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        TotalQty += basketItem.Quantity;                    
        Sku = variant.Sku;                          
        sbParams.Append(string.Format("?sku={0}&Qty={1}",Sku.Substring(0,4),TotalQty));

        popup = string.Format("window.open('http://somesite.ocm/cal.asp{0}','Reservation Calendar','width=265,height=465')",sbParams.ToString());
    btnCalendar.OnClientClick = popup;
     }
```

Calendar button:

```
    // Shows popup via OnClientClick
    public void btnCalendar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddPopup.Show();
    }
```

It works fine as a two-step process, click Setup and then click Calendar buttons.  If I move the setup code into the calendar routine it fails.  I'm sure this is because the Calendar button's OnClientClick is not set when it is clicked.

What is a best-practices type of way to do this without restructuring the whole program.  As I'm new to .NET programming I don't want to wreck the thing.

Comment: So the user needs to be able to select a date, based on that date see a popup of stuff, be able to select something from the popup and continue?

Comment: Yes, Romanarmy, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code to setup your `Button` on the `Page_Load` where it is typical to do much of the setup/prep for the page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         StringBuilder sbParams = new StringBuilder();
         TotalQty += basketItem.Quantity;
         Sku = variant.Sku;
         sbParams.Append(string.Format("?sku={0}&Qty={1}",
             Sku.Substring(0,4),TotalQty));
         popup = string.Format("window.open('http://somesite.ocm/cal.asp{0}', 
             'Reservation Calendar','width=265,height=465')", 
             sbParams.ToString());        
         btnCalendar.OnClientClick = popup;
     }
 }
```

The problem you have is your are trying to add something to the client side action using a server side method.  The client side method fires first and then the server side so if you add the function server side, the client side action has already passed it's execution point and does nothing.

If you need this `Button` to act differently or it is repeated multiple times, you should look into doing the setup during some bind action that is occuring.  If not just do it in the `Page_Load` at the start.

From your example I am not sure why you even care about the server side event so you could change your `OnClientClick` to be:

```
popup = string.Format("window.open('http://somesite.ocm/cal.asp{0}', 
    'Reservation Calendar','width=265,height=465'); return false;", 
    sbParams.ToString());
```

Notice the `return false;`.  This will cause the window to open but also tell the page to not post back to the server.

Comment: Thanks Kelsey. The reason I didn't do the button in Page_Load is that the quantities may change before they click the button. I need that to re-evaluate when they are ready to go to the calendar. The server side is where the quantities are set.

Comment: Although it's not the answer I was looking for, I'm marking this as the answer since it has some really good information in it, it's on target, and there's nothing better been offered.  All good reasons to give credit for help rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet might help you.

```
<asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:ShowPopup();"" ></asp:Button>
```

**JS**

```
function ShowPopup()
{
//Code for popup window

}
```